# aws iot core throttling indication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core

We are using the java v2 aws iot core sdk, and when trying to test publish and send 500 messages tp one client at once, only ~320 messages arrive to the client.
is this a throttling issue ? if so how can we check if published messages got throttled ?

Comment: did you check if you hit a quota limit which you might have to increase first? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#message-broker-limits

Comment: I am probably hitting a quota limit, the question it how to identify when it happens programmatically